# How to redirect Product Detail page to Home Page or 404 in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, redirect, 404, product-detail-page

How to redirect Product Detail Page to 404 or Home Page in Magento 2.4.

I don't want user to see product detail page in my store.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please check with my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `controller_action_predispatch_catalog_product_view` event to redirect user to 404 or home page.

In your custom module create

> Vendor/MyModule/etc/frontend/etc.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch_catalog_product_view">
        <observer name="custom_pdp_redirect" instance="Vendor\MyModule\Observer\Predispatch"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

> Vendor/MyModule/Observer/Predispatch.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\MyModule\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Predispatch implements ObserverInterface
{

    protected $_redirect;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_url;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $redirect,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    )
    {
        $this->_redirect = $redirect;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_url = $url;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        // To redirect to home page
        $homePageUrl  = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
        $this->_redirect->setRedirect($homePageUrl, 301);

        // To redirect to 404 page
        $norouteUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('noroute');
        $this->_redirect->setRedirect($norouteUrl, 301);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer it worked.
Will you please solve this also https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/340811/how-to-solve-sorry-something-went-wrong-please-try-again-later-on-magento-ver-2

Comment: Will check in whenever I am free :)