# How to Solve Sorry something went wrong Please try again later on Magento ver. 2.4.2-p1 Royal Mail Integration

Tags: error, patches, magento2.4.2, integration, mail

Sorry something went wrong Please try again later on Magento ver. 2.4.2-p1 Royal Mail Integration.

As, i have checked a patch is aval. here https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/68d20230ca9d6198fa3093eb174e24aff47b1646?branch=68d20230ca9d6198fa3093eb174e24aff47b1646&diff=split on this commit.

So, i have created all four files

```
app/code/Magento/Integration/Controller/Adminhtml/Integration/TokensExchange.php

   dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Integration/Controller/Adminhtml/Integration/TokensExchangeTest.php


dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Integration/_files/integration_all_data.php


dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Integration/_files/integration_all_data_rollback.php
```

But it doesn't apply here as it gives me same issue.

Is there any way to do that any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

The patch does resolve the issue and you'll need to compile files afterwards.

Amending the following file with the patch file resolves the issue entirely

vendor/magento/module-integration/Controller/Adminhtml/Integration/TokensExchange.php